# How do I use old typescript typings after npm package was removed and renamed?

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-typings

Recently, a number of packages I'm using were renamed. For example, `glue` was renamed to `@hapi/glue`. There are old typings that should still work fine available at `@types/glue`, but the typescript compiler will no longer use those; it searches for typings at `@types/hapi__glue`.

How do I configure typescript to use the old typings? Essentially, how do I create a typings alias?

Comment: Sidenote: Did you check if `@hapi/glue` already contains types and did you check if there is a `@types/hapi__glue` repo?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/hapi__glue says: `npm install --save @types/hapi__glue` and remove the old `@types/glue` one.

Answer (score 0):

You don' need an alias, remove the  old typings package and install [the new one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/hapi__glue):

```
npm install --save @types/hapi__glue
```